# How to create a frontend comment edit form without a plugin on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, comments, edit, frontend

I use the tinymce editor for creating comments and I need to make it available to users outside of the admin zone.

How do you do that without a plugin ?

I've tried every available plugin but they either don't work without breaking the javascript (ajax) or do not work at all.Thank you.

Edit : I installed the "Ajaxed Comments" plugin and got it to work by having it reload the whole page after the content has been submitted.

I am now trying to implement the wp_editor function either with jquery or PHP, without any success so far.